# ObjectAnimator animate LinearLayout width

Tags: android

Ok, so i checked out 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html

He says you can animate the property of an object in a given time. And i tried moving around objects and it looks fine. I encountered a problem when i went changing the width of a LinearLayout. I got this:

```
10-26 14:51:27.190: E/PropertyValuesHolder(12681): Couldn't find setter/getter for       property width with value type float
```

Then i tried extending LinearLayout, with "myWidth"

```
public void setMyWidth(int myWidth) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    params.weight = myWidth;
    setLayoutParams(params);
    requestLayout();
    this.myWidth = myWidth;
}
```

No luck. Then i tried changing LayoutParams.width, turns out width and height are the only public properties in java history, and ObjectAnimator needs getter and setter. No luck.
I'm embarassed to say i tried extending LayoutParams too... with no luck ofc.

Anybody succeded doing such a thing? I used old android.view.animation and i got what i wanted, but i'm curious for the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a similar issue. Instead of animating the width, I tried animating the weightSum (which DOES have a getter/setter) to achieve the same effect. Maybe you can try something similar to achieve what you want, but I can't get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341745/animating-weightsum-property-using-objectanimator. I'll keep you posted if I have some results

Answer (score 140):

In situations where there isn't a simple property getter/setter you should use [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#value-animator) and perform the animation manually.

Assuming:

- **v** is the view you're animating
- **END_WIDTH** is the target width of the view in pixels.
- **DURATION** is the desired length of the animation in milliseconds.

Your code should look something like this:

```
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(v.getMeasuredWidth(), END_WIDTH);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = v.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = val;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(DURATION);
    anim.start();
```

Comment: END_WIDTH ? Well I've already have this view inflated, in my xml layout it has match_content (0dp for constraint layout), so why I have to set it programmatically? Animation should be from 0px to size set in layout

Answer (score 22):

For what it's worth this works. After you change the width on the layout params you have to reset the layout params object.

```
private class WidthEvaluator extends IntEvaluator {

    private View v;
    public WidthEvaluator(View v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {
        int num = (Integer)super.evaluate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = num;
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        return num;
    }
}

// your client code
ValueAnimator.ofObject(new WidthEvaluator(box), box.getWidth(), v.getWidth()).start();
```

Comment: To make this work with nineOldAndroids, change the evaluate method signature to use Integer instead of Object. `public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue)`

Comment: Don't use evaluators to perform view changes. Add an `AnimatorUpdateListener` instead.

Comment: @BraisGabin so what would be the correct call?

Comment: add a listener and do it there

Answer (score 7):

I've created a small library [`ViewPropertyObjectAnimator`](https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator) that can do that in a very simple way (and uses a similar approach to this proposed by [Tomer Weller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16355027/1993204)).

You could achieve this animation with (assuming the `mLinearLayout` is the animated `View` and `mEndWidth` is the end value of the `View's` width):

```
ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(mLinearLayout).width(mEndWidth).start();
```

Answer (score 6):

You have made a mistake

```
 params.weight = myWidth;
```

I think it is **params.width** not **params.weight**

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to accomplish this would be to use View's scaleX and scaleY property which are defined all the way down in View class, so it would be valid with practically any view or layout.

For example, consider this

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(MyLinearLayout,"scaleX",0f,1f);
objectAnimator.setDuration(300);
objectAnimator.start();
```

It works.

Comment: No, it does not work. This scales, i.e. stretches, the view, which is way different from just enlarging it, keeping intact the proportions of the view's contents.

Comment: it just stretches view from the center but I need from left