# Change the weight of layout with an animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

In my main layout file, I have a RelativeLayout, with a weight of 1 (basically to display a map) above a LinearLayout with a weight of 2, declared this way :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GlobalLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/UpLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DownLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

DownLayout contains a list of items, when I click on an item, I would like to change the weight of DownLayout for 4, so the upper layout (the map) takes only 1/5 of the screen instead of 1/3.

I have managed to do it by changing the LayoutParams :

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.DownLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.weight = 4.0f;
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

It works but I'm not satisfied, the change is too immediate, there is no transition while I would like it to be smooth. Is there a way to use animation for that ?

I found some examples with ObjectAnimator to change the weightSum, but it does not do want I want (if I change only this property, I have some free space below my down layout) :

```
        float ws = mLinearLayout.getWeightSum();
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mLinearLayout, "weightSum", ws, 5.0f);
        anim.setDuration(3000);
        anim.addUpdateListener(this);
        anim.start();
```

Is there a way to use ObjectAnimator (or something else) to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 26):

I recently came across a similar problem and solved it using a standard Animation (I have to target API 10 so couldn't use ObjectAnimator).  I used a combination of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320002/1135276) with slight alterations to take into account weight instead of height.

My custom animation class looks as follows...

```
private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {

    private final float mStartWeight;
    private final float mDeltaWeight;

    public ExpandAnimation(float startWeight, float endWeight) {
        mStartWeight = startWeight;
        mDeltaWeight = endWeight - startWeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.weight = (mStartWeight + (mDeltaWeight * interpolatedTime));
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And its called by this method...

```
public void toggle() {
    Animation a;
    if (mExpanded) {
        a = new ExpandAnimation(mExpandedWeight, mCollapsedWeight);
        mListener.onCollapse(mContent);
    } else {
        a = new ExpandAnimation(mCollapsedWeight, mExpandedWeight);
        mListener.onExpand(mContent);
    }

    a.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
    mContent.startAnimation(a);
    mExpanded = !mExpanded;
}
```

Hopefully this will help you out, if you need more details or have questions about something let me know.

Comment: Thanks for that! I ended up doing something completely different, without animation, but I will definitely try your method!

Comment: @jbihan! can you share your method to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi! Actually, as I said above, I did something without animation, meaning I just used 2 simple activities, I didn't manage to have an animation smooth enough to make it look nice

Comment: Will this work if i try the same thing in a fragment too?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I used it for simultaneous weight change of several Views. It would be better if you add `mContent` to the constructor of the class.