# Animate layout_weight change

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

Is it possible to animate a layout_weight change of a View?

I have tried:

> ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(headerRoot,
>   "layout_weight", ws, 1f);
>           anim.setDuration(1500);
>           anim.addUpdateListener(this);
>           anim.start();

This has no effect on my layout. Is the objectAnimator able to manipulate the layout_weight property of a view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the weight of layout with an animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024591/change-the-weight-of-layout-with-an-animation)

Comment: instead of "layout_weight" you can use whatever e. g.  "blaBlaBla", then create a public void setBlaBlaBla(float f)  method in a class that you pass a first parameter to ObjectAnimator.ofFloat() add some Log.d inside that method and everything will be clear on how to proceed

Comment: and if you don't want to use an ObjectAnimator you can always use a ValueAnimator

Comment: see my answer to similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34090038/2712372

Answer (score 1):

Just use a class provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334557/1763138

```
private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {

    private final float mStartWeight;
    private final float mDeltaWeight;

    public ExpandAnimation(float startWeight, float endWeight) {
        mStartWeight = startWeight;
        mDeltaWeight = endWeight - startWeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.weight = (mStartWeight + (mDeltaWeight * interpolatedTime));
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and change `mContent` to your headerRoot

Answer (score 0):

> This has no effect on my layout. Is the objectAnimator able to manipulate the layout_weight property of a view?

No, it is not. `ObjectAnimator` uses the setter method of an object to update its value. A LayoutParam has not `setWeight` method, it only has the `weight` property you can change.

It's all explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator.