# Any way to do an animated crop on an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation, android-view, android-xml

Is there any way to animate a cropping of an ImageView?

Say for example, the ImageView is 720 x 480.  I want to chop off the bottom rows of pixels with an animation until the ImageView is completely gone.  I have only been able to move the image up when the onclicklistener is enabled, and make it transparent, which is ok, but not what the designer asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want to chop off the height, using `ObjectAnimator` will work out to create such a custom cropped-height animation,
First of all you need to specify `getHeight()` and `setHeight()` methods and then create a custom animation with `ObjectAnimator`.

```
public float getHeight() { ... }
public void setHeight(float h) { ... }

ObjectAnimator heightAnim= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourImageView, "height", heightBegin, heightEnd);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  I first had to get Jake Wharton's NineOldAndroids animation library to do as you suggested because I need to support < API 11.  Then I couldn't override getHeight() because height is final, so I had had to ValueAnimator.

Comment: You're welcome, yes and also ObjectAnimator added in API 11+, but JakeWhartons' library includes it also for devices < API 11

Answer (score 2):

```
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(myImageView.getMeasuredHeight(), 0);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = myImageView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = val;
            myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.start();
```

I got code from here and just changed it to height: [ObjectAnimator animate LinearLayout width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902976/objectanimator-animate-linearlayout-width)