# Progressbar along with text in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I would like to create `ProgressBar` along with text same as below.

[image]

Please guide me. I developed some design but I am not able to display text exactly right side of `ProgressBar` as progress bar take min width. Please see below image:
[image]

I am stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

My Code is:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lnrButtons"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button_selector">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:progress="50"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:indeterminate="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="10%"
                android:textColor="@color/light_orange"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBarHome"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

After implementing code changes output is:

[image]

Comment: try making a custom new where you increase its width for every tasks done

Comment: @anddev:let me know the below answer is helps you or not?

Answer (score 0):

You just design the layout according to that.I think your layout design will be following.

For eg.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ProgressBar
      style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/PROGRESS_BAR"
    >
    <TextView
        android:background="#00000000" // transparent background
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/PROGRESS_BAR"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

As per your requirement if you want to move your textview you have to pass your progress value to the following `txtView.setX((int) ur progress value);`

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: @anddev:Have you add horizontal style to the progressbar?

Comment: Yes. Please see my updated question. I have added my xml code.

Comment: After implementing as per your code, please refer output as per attached image above.

Comment: I think its done you just center ur textview by android:centerinparent="true"..it works

Comment: As I display in my first image I don't need to display text in center or any fix position but as progress will get increase the text view must be moved along with progress. That is my requirement.

Comment: @anddev:Is this answer is helps you or not..let me knw.

Comment: @win:as per my requirement your suggestion was not helpful to me. But then after instead of ProgressBar I added ImageView and create Bitmap programatically. Then It works as per my requirement. Thank you so much for your support and suggesstion. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the Android ValueAnimator should do the trick for you. Basically you need a custom shape for this progress bar, which you can animate to scale its width as and when the progress increases.

You might get some help here
[ObjectAnimator animate LinearLayout width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902976/objectanimator-animate-linearlayout-width)

Comment: use alignParentRight="true" for your textview