# android progress bar text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar

[image]

What I want to do is get the get progress from the progress bar and put some text at the end of the progress bar.

I'm not sure how to do this

Since the UI has to be made variably and putting a text view there, it doesn't come up no matter how much I think about it, and even if I google it, it doesn't come up.

If you know how, please help.

i want like this
[image]

[TextView on the right side of progress in ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425471/textview-on-the-right-side-of-progress-in-progressbar)

Comment: Usually you would want to put the text above the slider, so that the user can see it.  Putting it below the slider and having it follow where the user has their finger, they would never see the text since their finger would most likely be covering it.